# Silverstripe - FieldSet and FormAction limit? Increase the limit?

Tags: php, silverstripe

We are using Silverstripe 2.4. I have the form that has about 2000 fieldsets and a save button via FormAction. Everything as silverstripe form straight forward. The save function can only remember max 500 data array. Is there any where that I can increase the limit? Eventhough the page can render 2000 text fields.

```
<?php
  class ESM_Test extends Form {
     public $jsValidationIncluded = false;

     public function __construct($controller, $name, $systemId = null) {
       $fields = new FieldSet();
       //push 2000 text field into fieldset
       for ($i = 0; $i <2000; $i++) {
          $fields->push(new TextField('Test_'.$i,'Test_'.$i, $i));
       }
       $actions = new FieldSet();
       $saveButton = new FormAction('doSave', 'Save');
       $actions->push($saveButton);
       parent::__construct($controller, $name, $fields, $actions);
       $this->unsetValidator();
     }

     public function doSave($data, $form) {
       var_dump($data);  //I only get to 500 data array instead of 2000 data array
     }
 }
```

Comment: There's a PHP setting like "max post vars" or something. You may need to increase it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I increased max_input_vars to 2000 in php.ini and it worked!. Thanks Robbie Averill